# Make a parent div take height of child absolute positioned div

Tags: css, css-position

I want a parent div to take up the height of a static div + absolutely positioned div.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Maybe show us your HTML and what you're trying to accomplish, then we'll point you in the right direction. Unfortunately, @OneTrickPony might be right.

Comment: make the parent div also have a position absolute

Comment: An absolutely positioned element is taken out of the flow of the document. It is as if it is not the child of the element at all. There is no way this can be accomplished without JavaScript to read the size of the div and add  it to the parent div’s size.

Comment: Why don't you help us to help you by responding to the various comments that appear on your earlier questions? You are asking for us to design things which may not be possible with CSS, and since we can't tell if you are trying to design for a visual effect or to design around a HTML semantic constraint, it is hard to know what to suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Its not possible without JS as -dstorey told you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.   Something along the lines of this. I have not had a chance to test it, but it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var staticDiv = ('.staticDiv').height();
var absoluteDiv = ('.absoluteDiv').height();
var myHeight = staticDiv + absoluteDiv;
$('.parentDiv').css("height", myHeight); 
</script>
```